# Writing a recursive string function

Tags: c++, string, recursion

> Write a recursive, string -valued  function, replace, that accepts a string  and returns a new string  consisting of the original string  with each blank replaced with an asterisk (*) 
>   Replacing the blanks in a string  involves:
>
> Nothing if the string  is empty
>
> Otherwise:
>   If the first character  is not a blank, simply concatenate it with the result of replacing the rest of the string
>
> If the first character  IS a blank, concatenate an * with the result of replacing the rest of the string

Here's what I've tried:

```
string replace(string sentence){
    if(sentence.empty()) return sentence;

    string newString;

    if(sentence[0] == " ") {
      newString.append('*' + sentence.substr(1, sentence.length()));
    } else {
      newString.append(sentence.substr(1, sentence.length()));
    }

    return replace(newString);
}
```

But the website that tests the code for the correct answer is giving me the following error:

> CTest1.cpp: In function 'std::string replace(std::string)':
>
> CTest1.cpp:9: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Please note that the lines in the error don't necessarily correlate with the actual lines in the code.

Any suggestions?

**Update**

Solved it using the following code:

```
string replace(string sentence){
    if(sentence.empty()) return sentence;

    string newString;

    if(sentence[0] == ' ') {
        newString.append("*" + replace(sentence.substr(1)));
    } else {
        newString.append(sentence[0] + replace(sentence.substr(1)));
    }

    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string sentence;
if(sentence[0] == " ")
```

`" "` isn´t a single char, but a whole string. If you want a single blank, use `' '`

Comment: Thanks!  That resolved that error.  Any ideas why it says my return value is incorrect?

Comment: @inquisitor What does it say exactly?

Comment: It just tells me that replace does not return the correct value.  It's not compiled using an IDE, just an application my school uses to check output.

Comment: @inquisitor It doesn't return the correct output because in the case of a non-empty string which does *not* have a blank as the first character, it returns *the rest of the string after that character* at each recursive call. So, in the case of `"ABC"` it's going to return `""` since it removes one character each time it doesn't see a blank.

Comment: You want something more like `return '*' + replace(sentence.substr(1));` when you find a space... see how `replace` then works on successively less of the sentence?  As is, you're either misunderstanding what `append` does or how it might contribute to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. In if(sentence[0] == " "), sentence[0] is a character(which may be converted to its ascii value(integer) during comparison) and " " is an empty string or pointer to first character in an empty string. That is what is throwing the error.
2. Instead do if(sentence[0] == ' '). Also I am not sure in C++, but in java == checks for equality of references. so take care of it as well.
3. Also you need to append the result of replacing the rest of the string, not just the rest of the string. Write a recursive function for that

Comment: Your first two points are not (completely) correct. The code will do as intended in C++ (well, only for ASCII/Single-Byte UTF8, but you shouldn't be using string for unicode anyway), provided @dviantfan's  correction is made as `[]` returns `char` on `string`, not `string`. The 3rd point is correct however.